# How should i limit the number of characters interpretted by fscanf?

Tags: c, stdio

I'm writing a program to read from `stdin` and then writes what it reads to `stdout`, unescaping any escaped hex numbers it finds. All the numbers i want to read are 8 bit. This is what i have so far

```
while((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    if(c == '%') {
        fscanf(stdin,"%x",&r);
        printf("%i \n",r);
    }
}
```

This works fine, except for the fact that when i write something like `%FFF` to the standard input it reads it as a 3 digit hex number. How should i limit `fscanf` to reading only 2 characters? I have thought about reading the next 2 characters into a buffer and `sscanf'ing` that, but it feels rather inelegant to me.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to use `fgets()` to read a line at a time, use `strchr()` to find the `%` symbols, and do the hex conversion yourself?

Comment: No? Besides, there are no lines in this stream. It's hex.

Comment: So the input stream consists solely of `%XX` groups? (that can't be, because then how would you ever have a `%FFF` for that to be a problem?)

Comment: And anyway, even if your input consists of one infinitely-long line, it's still bound to be more efficient to use `fgets()` to fill a buffer and process the contents of the buffer than to perform a separate function call for each and every separate character of input.

Comment: Consider it an infinitely long line of characters, with a few escaped hex characters here and there. Why is that more efficient? Either way i'm still running the same number of operations on the same number of characters. The only difference is the characters reside in a buffer i provide myself instead of a buffer in the kernel. The fundamental algorithm won't have changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want `scanf` (et al) to read only two characters, then tell it to do so:

```
scanf("%2x", &r);
```

See e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for information about the `scanf` formatting.

Comment: I thought i had read the whole man page, i guess i missed this